# Token based authentication using Dapper micro-orm

Tags: asp.net-web-api, dapper, dapper-extensions

I am looking for tutorial or sample for Dapper using token based authentication in web api 2. I appreciate if anyone can suggest where to start, I have found tutorial in http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/ff2f08/token-based-authentication-using-Asp-Net-web-api-owin-and-i/ but the sample is using EF and I havent tried using EF, but dapper also I am using MySQL for my database. Thanks in advance and good day.

Comment: Dapper is just ORM, and nothing to do with Web API 2. Where do you get stuck exactly?

Comment: Sorry I am newbie in aps.net I just started about 2 months thank you for the correction in step 3 and step 4 in that tutorial thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dapper is a very different tool to EF (which is the `DbContext` described in your step 3 / step 4). It simply will not be compatible with those steps, and isn't designed to be used with those steps.

But here's the thing: dapper is just a tool. EF is just a tool. It is *ok* to use more than one tool. If it suits your purposes, then use EF to do one set of jobs (for example, to help you use a particular library that is designed with that in mind), and use another tool (such as dapper) *elsewhere in the same project*. That's OK. No one will mind.

If you really really don't want to use EF at all, then you'll need to find out everything that the library needs to support what you are doing, and implement it manually. If the library is designed around `IQueryable<T>` etc, then this may be very difficult.

Comment: so I can have both EF and Dapper at the same time, cool thanks :D

Comment: @jaketalledo absolutely! in fact, when we wrote dapper first of all, it was designed to work alongside our existing Linq-to-SQL generated types. Life will be easier if you keep the two things apart, of course (so: use dapper for A, B, and D, and Entity Framework for C, E and F, if you see what I mean). A common split example could be dapper for read-only view models, EF for data changes.

Comment: Sir I'm actually using fluent nhiberate for several of my project as Im more on no-sql (Linq) but i really have problem with the speed. A British guy suggested to me to used micro-orm Dapper the first time iv looked up in github Iv notice sql script. I really dont want to see that on my project lol. so I end up searching for Linq extension, what happen was several trial an error for refactor. and most of my problem is in IQueryable<T> and for Insert as I am using MySQL. it does not accept brackets for Insert and update. Any extension can you suggest Sir that works with MySQL INSERT using Linq

Comment: Oppss Sorry dapper for read-only view models, EF for data changes thanks a lot

Comment: @jake for the record, we use dapper for everything now (at least in new code) - the choice is entirely yours

Comment: I created a project where I used ASP.NET Identity Framework with EF just for the login and authentication. For everything else I used Dapper. It worked great.

Comment: @WayneBloss Great, can you show us an example project ?

Comment: @gtzinos Sorry, I can't - that project is private.

Comment: @WayneBloss I use OpenIddict but when i use authentication service it returns me MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException: Table 'ide.openiddictapplications'